# r- how to display the labels on the highcharter objects all the time

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

I have used a highcharter object including pie and bar chart, the label(percentage) display only the mouse moves on it. See code below:

```
library(highcharter)
data("favorite_bars")
data("favorite_pies")

highchart() %>% 
hc_title(text = "This is a bar graph describing my favorite pies
        including a pie chart describing my favorite bars") %>%
hc_subtitle(text = "In percentage of tastiness and awesomeness") %>% 
hc_add_series_labels_values(favorite_pies$pie, favorite_pies$percent, name = "Pie",
                          colorByPoint = TRUE, type = "column") %>% 
hc_add_series_labels_values(favorite_bars$bar, favorite_bars$percent,
                          colors = substr(terrain.colors(5), 0 , 7), type = "pie",
                          name = "Bar", colorByPoint = TRUE, center = c('35%', '10%'),
                          size = 100, dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE)) %>% 
hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "percentage of tastiness"),
       labels = list(format = "{value}%"), max = 100) %>% 
hc_xAxis(categories = favorite_pies$pie) %>% 
hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "{point.y}%") %>% 
hc_credits(enabled = TRUE, text = "Source: HIMYM",
         href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_J8QU1m0Ng",
         style = list(fontSize = "12px"))
```

And I want the percentage display all the time instead of mouse moves on it. See pics I got from highcharts official site:
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see on the [highcharts website](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) the options used to create the pie chart you pasted by clicking on **View options**.

You'll see, among others, the following code:

```
plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

This means you have to enable the dataLabels options and provide a formatter. In the code you provided, you can actually see in the second `hc_add_series_labels_values` call that the dataLabels `enabled` options is set to `FALSE`:

```
hc_add_series_labels_values(favorite_bars$bar, favorite_bars$percent,
                          colors = substr(terrain.colors(5), 0 , 7), type = "pie",
                          name = "Bar", colorByPoint = TRUE, center = c('35%', '10%'),
                          size = 100, dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE))
```

If you change it to `TRUE` you will see the labels. If you want the numbers to display as well, you have to pass a function to a `format` element in the list, like so:

```
hc_add_series_labels_values(favorite_bars$bar, favorite_bars$percent,
                              colors = substr(terrain.colors(5), 0 , 7), type = "pie",
                              name = "Bar", colorByPoint = TRUE, center = c('35%', '10%'),
                              size = 100, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
                                                            format = '{point.name}: {point.percentage:.1f} %'))
```

You'll then have to play with the different options to `dataLabels` to display them however you want, see the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels) for the Bar chart type for example.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and do you know how adjust the font size? Thanks.

Comment: In the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.dataLabels.style) you can see there is a `style` parameter for `dataLabels`. You need to add this to the `dataLabels` list in R, for example `style = list(fontSize = "6px")`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Im a Little late to this, but a simple way to do it is adding to the Code with a pipe

```
hc_plotOptions(pie = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}: {point.percentage:.1f} %")))
```